# Sending custom headers and cookies

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, header, xmlhttprequest

**Scenario :**
I want a form to be posted with my custom headers and cookies when i click the submit button .

I tried the below code to do , but it was failure

```
<html>
<body>
<form  action="https://www.example.com/test/alter/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Test" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="test@example.com" />
<input type="submit" onclick="test_post()" value="Submit request" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not good in js , i used the code below

```
<script>
function test_post(){
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Header1','Test_header');
document.cookie="userid=123;"
</script>
```

How can i submit the form with my custom headers and cookies , it is a XMLHttpRequest.

PS : Editing cookies and headers using  addons or console is not the requitement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your function isn't closed.
Have you considered using the [Axios HTTP client](https://github.com/axios/axios)?
https://github.com/axios/axios
Many designers prefer to avoid using old-school style xhr XMLHttpRequests. There are a number of ways these can go wrong.